# Access Android Framework strings

Tags: android

Can I access the strings in this file in my app?
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/main/core/res/res/values/strings.xml

What dependency should I need, what's the import for the R that I need?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

```
import android.R
```

the issue is that most of the strings there I can't access? why is that and how is it possible?

```
private var navBackDescriptionId: Int = 0

@StringRes
private fun getDescription(context: Context): Int {
    if (navBackDescriptionId <= Resources.ID_NULL) {
        val id = context.resources
            .getIdentifier("action_bar_up_description", "string", "android")
        navBackDescriptionId = if (id <= 0) {
            appBarStrings.ads_action_bar_up_description
        } else {
            id
        }
    }

    return navBackDescriptionId
}
```